troubleshooting touchscreen on Lenovo laptop running ubuntu 22.04.4
We have a Lenovo Yoga 730-13IKB running Ubuntu 22.04.4.  The  touchscreen was working for a very long time but a few months ago stop working entirely.  The stylus works fine.
xinput:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:02 06CB:7F8F Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:02 06CB:7F8F Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5173 Pen stylus                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5173 Finger touch               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5173 Pen eraser                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]

xinput list-props 12:
Device 'Wacom HID 5173 Finger touch':
    Device Enabled (188):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (320): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (321):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (322):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (323):    10.000000
    Device Node (312):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Wacom Tablet Area (367):    0, 0, 11748, 6608
    Wacom Rotation (368):   0
    Wacom Pressurecurve (369):  0, 0, 100, 100
    Wacom Serial IDs (370): 20851, 0, 3, 0, 0
    Wacom Serial ID binding (371):  0
    Wacom Pressure Threshold (373): 0
    Wacom Sample and Suppress (374):    2, 4
    Wacom Enable Touch (375):   1
    Wacom Enable Touch Gesture (377):   0
    Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters (378):   260, 72, 250
    Wacom Tool Type (379):  "TOUCH" (388)
    Wacom button action 0 (380):    1572865
    Wacom button action 1 (381):    1572866
    Wacom button action 2 (382):    1572867
    Wacom button action 3 (383):    1572872
    Wacom Button Actions (384): "Wacom button action 0" (380), "Wacom button action 1" (381), "Wacom button action 2" (382), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "Wacom button action 3" (383)
    Wacom Panscroll Threshold (386):    13
    Device Product ID (313):    1386, 20851
    Wacom Debug Levels (387):   0, 0

Running sudo cat /dev/input/event7 yields no output when I touch the screen, as opposed to the same command for input6, which is the stylus, which produces plentiful output when the stylus is used.
lsmod | grep touch:
hid_multitouch         36864  0
hid                   180224  6 i2c_hid,wacom,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,hid_generic

I have booted both a live Ubuntu 24.04 and live current Fedora and the touchscreen does not work on either.
What else can I do to help troubleshoot what is going on?  I will record the output of any commands that might be useful.
Thanks
